# Is there a way to access non leaf nodes in a C++ Boost rtree

Tags: c++, boost, r-tree

Sorry in advance, this a very specific question and I cannot provide any piece of code as this is for my job, thus confidential.

I am using the Boost R-trees, and an algorithm that I need to implement requires to access the non leaf nodes of the tree. With Boost rtree library, I only can access leaf nodes in an easy way. I noticed that there is a function to print all the nodes including the non leaf nodes (which means they exist, they are computed), with their position, their level in the tree etc, but I cannot access them the same way than the leaf nodes.

For now, the best solution that I have is to implement a visitor for the tree and overload the operator ()  to gather the nodes (this is what the print method does to access the nodes).

My question is, does anybody know an easier way to access the non leaf nodes ? Because this one does not seem to be efficient, and I'm loosing time each time I want to access a non leaf node. Moreover, I need to replicate the structure of the tree without the points, and I cannot do that if I cannot access the non leaf nodes.

Thank you in advance !

Comment: nobody is asking you to reveal company code. you are supposed to write a small example, that shows your issue. in most of the cases i can write such an example in a couple of minutes. don't be shy about quality / beauty. most of people around here are eager to help.

Comment: No the visitor is the blessed interface. If you need something "simpler" - just wrap it in the way you'd like it

Comment: a [mcve] is by definition not confidential, because it has only the minium required to demonstrate your problem. I dont think you need to include any confidential data to show an attempt of accessing a non-leave node ;)

Comment: Ok, you're right, but I'm really not allowed to share any piece of code that I wrote at work. This is the company policy :) Ok so @sehe you say that I should extract my nodes and build a 'custom tree' in which I can access all I want ? This is the usual way to do something like this?

Comment: @CsuGouv I don't see why you'd need to store it. I'd say if you feel that need, you probably need a different data structure. If the access patterns that rtree affords don't suit your use-cases then that's the problem.

Comment: @sehe Basically, a rtree is required for the algorithm I use. But I need to access all the nodes even the ones (non leaf nodes) that don't correspond to datapoints (leaf nodes), and I also need to replicate the tree without the points. The goal is to fill the duplicated tree with the processed points and to keep the unprocessed points in the original tree during the algorithm. I am pretty sure that I need a rtree because I trust the scientists who wrote the paper about the algorithm :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what would you like to do exactly so this will be a general answer.

In order to access the tree nodes for the first time you have to traverse the tree structure. In Boost.Geometry rtree visitor pattern is used for that. You could do it manually but internally Boost.Variant is used to represent the nodes so you'll end up with variant visitor instead. At this point you have a few options depending what are you going to do with the nodes. Are you going to modify the r-tree? Will the rtree be moved in memory? Will the addresses of nodes change? How many nodes are you going to access? Do you want to store some kind of reference to a node and traverse the tree structure from that point? Do you want to traverse the structure downward or upward?

One option as you noticed is to traverse the tree structure each time. This is a good approach if the tree structure can change. The obvious drawback is that you have to check all child nodes at each node using some condition (whatever you do in order to pick the node of interest).

If the tree structure does not change but the tree is copied to a different place in memory you can represent the node as a path from the root to the node of interest as list of indexes of child nodes. E.g. a list {1, 2, 3} meaning: traverse the tree using child node 1 of root node, then at the next level pick child node 2, then your node will be child node 3 at the next level. In this case you still have to traverse the tree but doesn't have to check conditions again.

If the tree does not change and nodes stays in the same place in memory you can simply use pointers or references.